Determine the header associated with each keyword in a row
Table example, with list of names (hundreds of them), and the sheet name details on the header (around 10-15 sheets).

Is it possible, with VBA code, to indicate where the word "CHECK" is in the column "result" of each row?
For example, in the Row 2 Column "Result", macro will automatically indicate the Sheets that contain word "Check" like Sheet 1 and Sheet 4.

Haven't you asked the same question already yesterday? What happened with that question?

When you ask a question it is good to frequently check if there are clarification questions, answers etc. You received three answers and it would be good to test them, send some feedback and choose (marking as accepted answer) the one which fit better your needs...

Please, try the next piece of code. It uses arrays and working mostly in memory should be fast enough even for large ranges to be processed:
Sub ExtractCheck()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, colRes As Range, arr, arrCheck
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, strCheck As String
 Const res As String = "Result"   'header to be searched for
 Const strChk As String = "Check" 'use here the string to be searched (Check, OK etc.)
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet name
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row      'last row on A:A column
 Set colRes = ws.rows(1).Find(what:=res, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'find Result column
 
 If colRes Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No ""Result"" column header has been found...": Exit Sub
 
 arr = ws.Range("B1", ws.cells(lastR, colRes.column - 1)).Value2 'place the range in an aray for faster processing
 
 ReDim arrCheck(1 To lastR - 1, 1 To 1) 'redim the necessary array (one column)
 For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    strCheck = strChk & " " 'initialize strCheck
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If arr(i, j) = strChk Then strCheck = strCheck & arr(1, j) & ", "
    Next j
    If strCheck <> strChk & " " Then 'if at least a searched string has been found:
        arrCheck(i - 1, 1) = left(strCheck, Len(strCheck) - 2) 'eliminate the ending ", " part
    End If
 Next
 
 'drop the array content, at once:
 colRes.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrCheck), 1).Value2 = arrCheck
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

The above code does not need to specify how many sheets/columns exist. It calculates after finding the marker header (res). I mean, no need to adapt anything after adding columns for sheets name...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.
I commented all code lines to make the code easy to be understood. If still something not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

I suggest you create a callable function that you can execute from the result cell. It takes the range of cells that contain the status text (OK or Check) and the range of cells with the sheet names as two arguments. It builds the text to be shown in the result based on those ranges:
Option Explicit

Public Function ShowResult(rStatus As Range, SheetNames As Range) As String
    Dim status As Variant
    Dim ix As Integer: ix = 0
    Dim sMsg As String: sMsg = ""
    For Each status In rStatus
        ix = ix + 1
        If status = "Check" Then
            sMsg = sMsg + IIf(Len(sMsg) > 0, ", ", "") & SheetNames.Cells(ix)
        End If
    Next status

    '// Amended code 2024-08-05
    If Len(sMsg) = 0 Then ShowResult = "OK" Else ShowResult = "Check " & sMsg

End Function

In the sheet just call the function in the Result cell like this:

This has the advantage of flexibility and resilience - when you change the layout, like adding more sheets, the function still works.

You've recreated Excel's own TextJoin function..?

Maybe you could use TEXTJOIN, but I think there would have to be some sort of pre-processing to check if the cells indicating status were OK or Check, and to return the name of the sheet to be joined to the string. Not sure that would be any easier.

See my answer for a TEXTJOIN solution.  I'm not saying it's easier, but if OP asks for VBA they may not realise it can be done without.

Populate Delimited Matches
Before

After

Sub PopulateCheckColumn()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LIST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B3"
    
    Const FIRST_CHECK_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const LAST_CHECK_COLUMN As Long = 4
    Const RESULT_COLUMN As Long = 5
    
    Const MATCH_STRING As String = "Check"
    Const RESULT_PREFIX As String = "Check "
    Const RESULT_NO_MATCH As String = "Ok"
    Const DELIMITER As String = ", "
    Const LAST_DELIMITER As String = ", and "
    
    ' Reference the main objects (workbook, worksheet, range).
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim fcell As Range: Set fcell = ws.Range(LIST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With fcell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set rg = fcell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - fcell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - fcell.Column)
    End With
     
    ' Check the size of the range against the inputs (constants).
     
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
    
    If rCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found in sheet """ & ws.Name & """ of workbook """ _
            & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    If cCount < Application.Max( _
            Array(NAME_COLUMN, LAST_CHECK_COLUMN, RESULT_COLUMN)) Then
        MsgBox "Not enough columns in sheet """ & ws.Name & """ of workbook """ _
            & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Return the header and data values in arrays.
    
    Dim hData() As Variant: hData = rg.Rows(1).Value
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = drg.Value
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the data array and by looping through columns,
    ' build the resulting string. Copy it to the first column of the array
    ' to be able to copy to the resulting column in one go.
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim BuiltString As String, PreviousString As String, NextString As String
    Dim IsFirstFound As Boolean, IsSecondFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = FIRST_CHECK_COLUMN To LAST_CHECK_COLUMN
            Value = dData(r, c)
            If Not IsError(Value) Then
                If StrComp(CStr(Value), MATCH_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    NextString = CStr(hData(1, c))
                    If IsFirstFound Then
                        If IsSecondFound Then
                            BuiltString = BuiltString _
                                & DELIMITER & PreviousString
                        Else
                            IsSecondFound = True
                        End If
                        PreviousString = NextString
                    Else
                        BuiltString = NextString
                        IsFirstFound = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        If IsFirstFound Then
            If IsSecondFound Then
                BuiltString = BuiltString & LAST_DELIMITER & PreviousString
                IsSecondFound = False ' reset for the next iteration
            End If
            dData(r, 1) = RESULT_PREFIX & BuiltString
            IsFirstFound = False ' reset for the next iteration
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = RESULT_NO_MATCH
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Copy the first (resulting) column of the array 
    ' to the resulting column of the range.
    
    With drg.Columns(RESULT_COLUMN)
        .Value = dData ' copy
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit ' format?
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Check column populated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


Is there any reason you want a macro? Would you be happier with a formula?
Enter the following in F2:
="Check "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2:E2="Check",B$1:E$1,""))
                                   ^              ^
            Change these two Es to the column your table ends at

Then, copy down.
Result:

While your sample data doesn't include the possiblity of zero "Check" entries on a line, the following would result in "OK" if none were found:
=IF(AND(B2:E2="OK"),"OK","Check "&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(B2:E2="Check",B$1:E$1,"")))

Result:

